# How do I close the camera interface after a certain time on xcode in swift2 and open a different view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

So I have a button in the initial control view which takes the user to the camera interface. The user goes back to the initial view controller after taking a photo but how do I make the app close the camera and return to the initial page or a different page after a certain time period if the user doesn't take a picture.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var CameraButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var photoLibrary: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


@IBAction func cameraAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func photoLibraryAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageView.image = info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage;
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a `NSTimer` that gets started when you present the image picker. Set your desired waiting time.
2. Then, in timer fire method dismiss the image picker.
3. If user dismisses the image picker before the timer fires, invalidate the timer in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`